# Run Javascript custom function in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, c#, phantomjs

I am writing a console application in which I am using Nreco.PhantomJS to load the data. This is a scrapping application for a website containing google map with markers on it. The data I am trying to get is not available on the page before or after it is loaded completely. The data is the simple Latitude and Longitude that is passed from a JavaScript function to the google map and is not rendered on the page. As I am very new to PhantomJS so I am not sure how to achieve this but I am sure this can be done. This small piece of script is run by me in c# code,

```
try
{
    string jsContent = "var system = require('system');" +
    "var page = require('webpage').create();" +
    "page.open('" + url + "', function(status) {" +

        "system.stdout.writeLine(GetLatLang());" +
    "}"+

    "phantom.exit();" +
    "});";

    phantomJS.RunScript(jsContent, null, null, ms);
}
finally
{
    phantomJS.Abort(); // ensure that phantomjs.exe is stopped
}
```

When I call `Alert(GetLatLang())` function in console tab (Inside google chrome inspector) then it run fines and value is retrieved. However the PhantomJS never finishes running the code and I have to close the application. My understanding is that in the above code PhantomJS immediately try to execute the `GetLatLang()` function whereas it is not available at that time. Is there any way to execute this function after the page is completely loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `GetLatLang()` function in the page context and not in the phantom context:

```
"page.open('" + url + "', function(status) {" +
    "console.log(page.evaluate(function(){" +
        "return GetLatLang();" +
    "}));" +
"}"+
```

[`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) is the only function that provides access to the DOM and the page's `window` object.

---

Additionally, your JavaScript has a syntax error. There is only one opening `{`, but two closing `}`. You need to remove `"}"+`.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. The javascript error you pointed was due to that I removed couple of unnecessary lines to make code more understandable.